# Setting Java Heap Space in Weblogic Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, out-of-memory, weblogic, heap-memory

I have my Java EE web application deployed and running in Weblogic server.

If I want to set min and max arguments like this, Xms100m Xmx500m, where should I change this?

Whether in `Weblogic 10.0MP` server (if so, where) or while building the application in IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Admin Server this can be done in `$domain_home/bin/setDomainEnv.sh` (most likely corresponding bat if you use Windows) script, for managed servers via Weblogic console.

Comment: Can you tell where exactly in weblogic console for managed servers?

Comment: I do not remember exactly and these things tend to change from version to other. But here it is told in details: https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/weblogic_server_performance_and_tuning

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting weblogic form IDE like Eclipse you can change this in Run Configuration options (JVM Arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in Server Start arguments as described here:
http://itbitsolutions.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/increasing-the-heap-size-of-the-jvm/

after changing, you need to restart servers to apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable USER_MEM_ARGS on WLS 12c.

For instance:

```
-Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Don't forget the MaxPermSize, or it will default and probably niet be enough.